# Select rows by indices - Pandas loc - any missing labels

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, label, pandas-loc

Python version 3.8.5 / Pandas version 1.1.2

To display the rows of the indices from 0 to 99, I used

```
df[df.col_1 > 60].loc[range(0,99), 'col_2']
```

But I've got this error message

> KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is
> no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([
> 1,  3,  4,  6,  7,\n            ...\n            95, 96, 97, 98,
> 99],\n           dtype='int64', length=72). See
> [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%22)

For an alternative, I have this option which is working for my case:

```py
df[df.col_1 > 2].loc[0:4, 'col_2']
```

I heard that it's no longer accepted for the new pandas version.
Thanks for any confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is better chain 2 masks by `&` and pass to one `loc`:

```
df[(df.col_1 > 60) & df.index.isin(range(99)), 'col_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

beacause of the filter df.col1>60 some of the indices are not present in the dataframe but u gave an argument of range(0,99) in loc so as they are not present it raised an error. if u want 100 elements.
use this

```
df[df.col_1 > 60].iloc[range(0,99), 'col_2']
```

if u want with in 1st hundred elements try this:

```
df=df.loc[range(99), ["col_1",'col_2']]
df[df[loc_1]>60].drop("col_1",axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in the below way.

Here instead of considering all values of `range(99)`, we are taking intersection.

```
df[df.col_1 > 60].loc[df[df.col_1 > 60].index.intersection(range(99)), 'col_2']
```